# Open-Telemetry and autoinstrumentation of project libraries

Tags: java, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I'm using a Java-Application and trying to use the OpenTelemetrys Java autoinstrumentation. It looks like, that the autoinstrumentation does only work ond code directly call from the application itself and dependencies are not instrumented?

The project uses a dependency which itself uses Apache HttpClient for sending Requests to a remote server. These requests however seem not to be instrumented. When doing a request directly in my application as well, it works as expected.

Is there a way to tell the agent, that a specific dependency has to be instrumented as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instrumentation of Apache HttpClient works fine for me, even when using transitive dependencies except for the newer httpclient5. After a quick look on the sources of the [instrumentation agent](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/apache-httpclient/apache-httpclient-4.0/javaagent/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/apachehttpclient/) it seems only HttpClient 4 is supported at the moment

Comment: Thanks, the library I use does indeed use HttpClient5. So it does not work as for this reason.